# CSS columns don't work with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm making a web page with a Pinterest style, however the columns property do not work in Firefox.

[This is the example that I am following](http://www.tutorialmonsters.com/ejemplos/CSS-pinterest-columnas/ejemplo.html), you can try it in Firefox.

This is the relevant CSS:

```
#columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know *why* yet, but Firefox doesn't like `-moz-column-fill: auto`, remove it and the example works fine. The initial value for `column-fill` is `balance` ([read more on `column-fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) here)

```css
body > div {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-moz-column-fill: auto;*/
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
body > div > div {
  background: #F00;
  height: 400px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```